# Batch renaming files in Unix

Tags: regex, unix, rename

Asked on Unix stack exchange, but no answers:

I need help renaming files in batch--the other questions I browsed don't exactly address my problem. The names of my files are generated non-deterministically, so I can't predict what they will be named. I do know that they will start with `NORMAL` and end with `-lib*`. I'd like to replace everything in between with some string `X`. For example,

```
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.concordant
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.deletion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.divergent
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.inversion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.translocation
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.concordant
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.deletion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.divergent
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.insertion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.inversion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.translocation
```

So it will probably be of the form `rename "s/something/X/"`, but I don't know what that something should be, as I don't know how to use regex. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What would be the expected output for the first file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably work. If it prints out the right thing, remove the `echo` from the mv line.

```
for i in NORMAL*lib*
do
   echo mv $i `echo $i | sed -e 's/NORMAL_.*-lib/NORMAL_X-lib/'`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below command on the directory where the files you want to rename are stored.

```
rename 's/^(NORMAL)(.*)(-lib.*)$/$1X$3/' *
```

After running the above command `NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.concordant` file renamed to `NORMAL-lib1.concordant` likewise for all.